# Column colapses on itself in IE

Tags: html, css

I have a column here: http://www.animactions.ca/contact.php

It has contact information. Click contact a few times and you'll notice the text collapses itself. It happens randomly and I don't understand why?
(only with Internet Explorer)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked in IE8 and IE7 and there wasn't a problem.

Comment: Did you try refreshing several times?

Comment: Yes, but I still don't have a project.